# Get exception "System.TypeInitializationException,WebSphereMQ.<Command Name>" - mo74_PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ibm-mq

I'm trying to use mo74 library but I always get exception "System.TypeInitializationException,WebSphereMQ.".

Library is installed (I can get help by WMQ commands).

The link from where I downloaded it - http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24017698
Configuration:

```
    Windows Server 2008R2
    PSVersion 2.0
    Broker Version 7.0.0.5
```

Also tried on Windows 7, PS 2.0, Broker 7.0.0.5, Windows Server 2012, PS 4.0, Broker 7.0.0.0 with same result.

After install I tried to add WebSphereMQ.dll to GAC

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.EnterpriseServices") | Out-Null 
[System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish] $publish = new-object  System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish
$publish.GacInstall(<<FullFilePathToTheDll>>)
```

But it didn't help.

Full exception:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WMQQueue SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LOCAL.QUEUE
Get-WMQQueue : The type initializer for 'IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.BindingsNmqiMQ' threw an exception.
At line:1 char:13
+ Get-WMQQueue <<<<  SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LOCAL.QUEUE
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WMQQueue], TypeInitializationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.TypeInitializationException,WebSphereMQ.GetWMQQueue
```

Thanks for answers in advance!

Comment: Shot in the dark but you don't mention the architecture of the running PowerShell instance. The installation appears to be x86 architecture. Are you running a 32-bit shell?

Comment: Matt, it is 64-bit operation system, for execute script I used Windows PowerShell (x86)

Comment: You didn't mention having any MQ components installed.  What's the output when you run `dspmqver -a`?

Comment: Can you please post the complete exception stack?

Comment: Shashi, added to the question text in main theme - "Full exception".

Comment: @AndreyLolcost - I am told that the issue has been resolved in an upcoming version of MO74. Please contact developers of MO74 for availability of the update. Developers can be contacted via the email id provided in this document: ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/integration/support/supportpacs/individual/mo74.pdf

Comment: Shashi, thanks! Developers have provided the new version 02.06.2015. It works =)
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24017698

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem have been solved in the new version of the driver.
Link - http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24017698